# Entity framework re-inserts the foreign key reference values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the below entity structure.

```
public class Student
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public class University
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public class Subject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        //A student may have to go many universities for the courses in the curriculum
        public class UniversityStudentAssociation
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Student Student { get; set; }
            public University University { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        }
```

My entity data is as below. The student should decide which course(s) he needs to opt for and from which university.

The student Roger needs to take two courses from MIT and 2 courses from Harvard

This data is obtained from the client side as view models and converted to entities.

```
var universityStudentAssociations = new List<UniversityStudentAssociation>
            {
                //New association
                new UniversityStudentAssociation
                {
                    Id=0,
                    //Already existing student
                    Student=new Student
                    {
                        Id=1,
                        Name="Roger"
                    },
                    //Existing university
                    University= new University
                    {
                        Id=1,
                        Name="MIT"
                    },
                    Subjects=new List<Subject>
                    {
                        //Existing Subject
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Id=1,
                            Name="Psychology"
                        },
                        //Existing Subject
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Id=2,
                            Name="Sociology"
                        }
                    }
                },
                //New association
                new UniversityStudentAssociation
                {
                    Id=0,
                    //Already existing student
                    Student=new Student
                    {
                        Id=1,
                        Name="Roger"
                    },
                    //Existing university
                    University= new University
                    {
                        Id=2,
                        Name="Harvard"
                    },
                    Subjects=new List<Subject>
                    {
                        //Existing Subject
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Id=3,
                            Name="Physics"
                        },
                        //Existing Subject
                        new Subject
                        {
                            Id=4,
                            Name="Mathematics"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Entity framework while inserting the data, assumes the student (Roger) object, the University (MIT and Harvard) and Subjects (Physics,Mathematics,Psychology and Sociology) needs to be re-inserted. But, it needs to just refer to Student, University and Subjects tables as foreign keys in UniversityStudentAssociation table.

Hence, every time I try to insert the above data, Entity framework inserts 2 new students, 2 new Universities and 4
Subjects into the respective tables.

Please help me on how I can tell Entity framework to refer to existing data and not insert new data.

I know the data seems bizzare. But, my business logic is analogous (I couldn't have used that here) to the entity class structure I have mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to create a student variable before creating the associations `var student = new Student { Id = 1, Name="Roger"};`, then just assign the variable to Student in both associations `Student = student,`.

Comment: Students, Universities and Subjects already exist in the DB. Only UniversityStudentAssociation will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that your `DbSet<...>` classes in your `DbContext` represent the tables in your database.

The class in `DbSet<...>` represents one row within the table, and the relations between this row and rows from other tables.

> In entity framework, the non-virtual properties represent the columnts of the tables, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many)

It seems to me that there is a one-to-many relation between Student and UniversityStudentAssociation: every Student has zero or more UniversityStudentAssociations and every UniversityStudentAssociation belongs to exactly one Student, namely the Student that property `Student` refers to.

Similarly there seems to be a one-to-many relation between University and UniversityStudentAssociation: every University has zero or more UniversityStudentAssociations and every UniversityStudentAssociation belongs to exactly one University, namely the University that property `University` refers to.

Because of these two one-to-many relations, there is in fact a many-to-many relation between Student and University: every Student attends zero or more Universities, and every University teaches zero or more Students. Table UniversityStudentAssociation serves as an (extended) junction table to implement this many-to-many relation (See [many-to-many relations](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships#manytomany))

If you follow the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) your classes will be as follows.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // every Student has zero or more UniversityStudentAssociations (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<UniversityStudentAssociation> UniversityStudentAssociations {get; set;}
}

public class University
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // every University has zero or more UniversityStudentAssociations (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<UniversityStudentAssociation> UniversityStudentAssociations {get; set;}
}
```

Class UniversityStudentAssociation:

```
public class UniversityStudentAssociation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    // Every UniversityStudentAssociation belongs to exactly one Student, using foreign key
    public int StudentId {get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    // Every UniversityStudentAssociation belongs to exactly one University, using foreign key
    public int UniversityId {get; set; }
    public virtual University University { get; set; }

    // Every UniversityStudentAssociation has zero or more Subjects (one-to-many)
    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the Subject class:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // every Subject belongs to exactly one UniversityStudentAssociation using foreign key
    public int UniversityStudentAssociationId {get; set; }
    public virtual UniversityStudentAssociation UniversityStudentAssociation {get; set;}
}
```

Note that I added virtual members to inform entity framework about the relations between the tables. Because one side has a virtual ICollection<...> and the other side a single virtual element, entity framework knows that this is a one-to-many relationship.

Another important change is the addition of the foreign keys. If you omit them, entity framework will add them anyway. I added them, because the non-virtual properties of the class represents the columns in your table. I want to make clear what columns the table has. Besides sometimes it enables you to do certain joins if you can't use the virtual collections.

Usually if you want to "get items with (some or all of) their subitems, you can use the Collections:

> > Give me (some properties of) all students that live in New York and (some properties of) all the universities they attend

```
var result = dbContext.Students
    .Where(student => student.City == "New York)
    .Select(student => new
    {
        // Select only the Student properties that you plan to use:
        Id = student.Id,
        Name = student.Name,
        ...

        Universities = student.UniversityStudentAssociations
            .Select(association => new
        {
            // I only want the university properties
            // again: only the properties that you plan to use:
            UniversityId = association.University.Id,
            UniversityName = association.University.Name,
    }
```

Comment: Did this. But no luck :-(

Comment: What is your problem after the changes?

Comment: New students, subjects and universities are inserted. I already have Roger with id 1 in students table. After I do dbContext.UniversityStudentAssociations.Add(data) and save changes on my dbContext, Roger is inserted into student table with id 2. Same is going on for subject and university as well.